# Trinamic TMC2209 STM32 UART not reading from device

Tags: stm32, uart, stepper, usart, stm32f1

I've been struggling for ages, finally caved and asking for help now.
There are very little resources on STM32 for this driver that I have seen.

I can use the device with the STEP/DIR interface but I want to be able to do the more advanced things now with only the single UART line and not the STEP/DIR lines.

I am trying to control a TMC2209 in the most basic form to understand how it all works, without libraries and such.
I want to get basic controls working so I can understand it and build up my own code from there, right now the goal is to just talk to the thing and get it to spin.

I am using a STM32F103, I have setup the USART3 line (PC10) in signal wire half duplex mode and using the following code to try read from the CHOPCONF register.

```
       Sync = 0x05; // sync byte to start the Tx
       Address = 0x00; // MS1 and MS2 are pulled low so the device address is 0
       RegAddress = 0x6C; // Trying for a basic read from the CHOPCONF Reg
       motor_CRC = 0xCA;  // CRC that has been worked out

       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,&Sync,sizeof(Sync),20);
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,&Address,sizeof(Address),20);
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,&RegAddress,sizeof(RegAddress),20);
       HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,&motor_CRC,sizeof(motor_CRC),20);

// Receive the data from the TMC2209

       HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, &ReplySync, sizeof(ReplySync), 200);
       HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, &ReplyMasterAddr, sizeof(ReplyMaster), 20);
       HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, &ReplyAddr, sizeof(ReplyAddr), 20);
       HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, &Reply1, sizeof(Reply1), 20);
       HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, &Reply2, sizeof(Reply2), 20);
       HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, &Reply3, sizeof(Reply3), 20);
       HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, &Reply4, sizeof(Reply4), 20);
       HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, &ReplyCRC, sizeof(ReplyCRC), 20);

       HAL_Delay(1000);
```

**I expect the following :** ( according to the Datasheet that is,,, )

```
ReplySync      >>> 0x05
ReplyMasterAddr>>> 0xFF
ReplyAddr      >>> 0xCA
Reply1         >>> 0x53
Reply2         >>> 0x00
Reply3         >>> 0x00
Reply4         >>> 0x10
ReplyCRC       >>> I dont know this one yet,,,,
```

**But I am getting this :**

```
ReplySync      >>> 0x05
ReplyMasterAddr>>> 0x00
ReplyAddr      >>> 0x5D
Reply1         >>> 0x09
Reply2         >>> 0x08
Reply3         >>> 0x00
Reply4         >>> 0x02
ReplyCRC       >>> 0x09
```

I am not sure if I am transmitting these in the correct order or maybe the HAL function should not be used for this at all ?

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the actual reply stable, i.e. repats every time?

Comment: Yup, I run it over and over and get the same thing, reset the board and still the same output.

Answer (score 0):

So it has been a while but I did manage to get this working a while back.
I'll try give as much info as I can remember to how I made this work.

My UART comms ened up being this;

```
// THIS SETUP DOES NOT MATTER IF YOU DONT CARE ABOUT STALL DETECTION AND OTHER FETURES, MAYBE JUST DO THE FIRST ONE FOR UART COMMS
      uint8_t FullSetup[]={0x05 ,0x00 ,0x80 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x01 ,0xe1 ,0x63,// This address will need to be changed if directed at anything but the hood motor
                           0x05 ,0x00 ,0xec ,0x12 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x53 ,0x07,
                           0x05 ,0x00 ,0xF0 ,0x24 ,0x00 ,0x70 ,0x2C ,0xD7, // setting the PWM Conf Reg for Stealth Chop
                           0x05 ,0x00 ,0x94 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0f ,0xa0 ,0x3b, // stall guard detection, make sure this is the lowest value used (4000 now)
                           0x05 ,0x00 ,0xc2 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x45,
                           0x05 ,0x00 ,0xa2 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x0E};  // last thing is set the speed to Zero
```

I used the same CRC checker that was given in the examples and sent it with this:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(AUX_MOTOR_UART_CH, FullSetup, sizeof(FullSetup),100);  // sets the main operating details needed. DOES NOT SET direction, speed or stall value
```

For those who need it the stall value I set by doing this :

```
uint8_t StallV[] = {0x05 ,0x00 ,0xc0 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x00 ,0x8D}; // Set the motor stall value

                StallV[6]= hoodMotorBuffer.Stall;//Stall[HoodTracker]+(hoodMotorBuffer.Stall);
                TMC2209_calcCRC(StallV, sizeof(StallV));
                HAL_UART_Transmit(AUX_MOTOR_UART_CH, StallV, sizeof(StallV),1); // send Stall value.
```

Hope this helps someone.